# How to not overwrite files in git

Tags: git

I'm using a GIT controlled hosting. And everytime I make a commit and push, my .htaccess is overwritten. There is anyway to "remove" or "ignore" the .htaccess, so I can remove the local file and not overwrite the remote version?

Comment: Has .htaccess already been added to the git repository, or is it only a local file? You can usually add files to "ignore" to a .gitignore file.

Comment: @OnlineCop was already been added, but I solved "removing" the local file and adding a "gitignore". Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I just solved the question. I was dumb to ask the question without searching correctly on Google.

I got a "gitignore example" from GitHub for WordPress, as you can see here:

```
.htaccess
wp-content/uploads/
wp-content/blogs.dir/
wp-content/upgrade/
wp-content/backup-db/
wp-content/advanced-cache.php
wp-content/wp-cache-config.php
sitemap.xml
*.log
wp-content/cache/
wp-content/backups/
sitemap.xml.gz
wp-config.php
```

Then I did a `git rm --cached`, a commit and then I pushed to my server.

Thanks Linwei for the answer, was fast :P

Answer (score 3):

First remove your .htaccess file from your git repository without deleting it using this command:

```
     git rm --cached .htaccess
```

Then add .htaccess file to your .gitignore file.

Now whenever you push git will ignore your local htaccess file